# CURRENT_TIMESTAMP doesn't match current time on server

Tags: mysql, sql, linux

```
SELECT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

returns the time as 18:00 roughly. However, when running

```
SELECT @@global.time_zone, @@session.time_zone;
```

the result is SYSTEM and SYSTEM. Running the 'date' command on my Linux server returns the time as approximately 13:00. How are these two times different?

Comment: Which RDBMS is this?

Comment: also system_time_zone is apparently set to UTC despite the timezone on my server being CDT

Answer (score 1):

Solution: After changing the timezone on my server, I did not actually restart mysql. I simply reconnected. For anyone curious to restart:

```
/etc/init.d/mysqld restart
```

(u may have to sudo)